# How to rename Joomla folder in shared web on Synology NAS

Tags: joomla, nas, synology

I just installed Joomla application into my Synology NAS from the available Package Center and I tried to rename the "joomla" folder inside shared web in File Station. It's failed my Joomla service.

I am able to rename it as "abc" but unfortunately it is effect to my URL when browsing and also to my joomla in Package Center. The Synology Package Center detect as Offline. However after I rename the folder back to from "abc" to "joomla". It getting online as well.

I don't want to use "joomla" folder name. I want to change to another name instead of "joomla". Any body have an experience like this? Can anyone help.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to change the Site Name setting in the administrator/backend? https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/site-settings/modify-site-name  (In the future, please post Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: No, I mean the folder name of "joomla" in Synology, not the site name. My problem is relate to Synology it self.

Comment: @mastersuse did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @schumacher574, I don't remember whether I found the solution or not.